# How to use a where clause on all instances of an attribute

Tags: sql, where-clause

This question is quite vague so I will just give an example

If I have a DB with for example a country attribute, where the country can appear more than once, how could I check that another attribute, called building, is null in all instances of that country?

And how would you do this for all countries? i.e. check that all buildings are null for a group of the same country, for every country.

```
country | building
      --+--
USA     | null
USA     | null
USA     | 2
Germany | null
Germany | null
Nepal   | null
Spain   | 3
```

The query should return Germany and Nepal if you select country. Totally arbitrary example but it should get the point across.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: this is called Relational Division, if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked in Postgres: `select country from countries where country not in (select country from countries where building is not null) group by country order by country;`

Where `countries` is the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one, using group by:

```
SELECT country FROM countries group by country having sum(building) is null;
```

I've tested this in MySql and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct country 
    from #table t 
    where not exists 
     (select 1 from #table t1 where t1.country = t.country and t1.building is not null)
```